# What's the equivalent in asyncio of gevent.sleep(0)

Tags: python, gevent, python-asyncio

If I want some code to run later I can call gevent.sleep(0) to yield from current greenlet, how to handle it in asyncio?
e.g.

```py
def spawn(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return gevent.spawn(f, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


@spawn
def f(a, b):
    gevent.sleep(0)  # gevent.idle()
    print(a + b)


@spawn
def g():
    print("hello")


f(1, 3)
f(4, 5)
g()

gevent.sleep(3)

"""
Expected:
hello
4
9
"""
```

of this case g will run ahead of f. In asyncio is there something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of `gevent.sleep(time)` would be `await asyncio.sleep(time)` in `asyncio`. If you call `await asyncio.sleep(time)` would sleep/block the caller **task** and if there are other tasks available they will run. After the declared `time` passes, caller task will be available for execution.

Example:

```py
import asyncio

async def f():
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print('This is function f!')

async def g():
    print("This is function g!")

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(f())
    loop.create_task(g())
    await asyncio.sleep(10)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: @JohnSmith If what you asked was ```gevent.idle()``` the answer will change. Do you want to sleep the ```f()``` until ```g()``` is complete? You could use [events.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Event) If that's the case I will update the code.